# EntityCommand Delete Operation

Tags: entity-framework

Is it possiple to do delete operation using EntityCommand without using Stored Porcedures?
If no, what are the possiblity to do that using entity key only, without retrieving the whole Entity Object.
I don't want to use Delete method of ObjectContext!!
Something like ExecuteCommand in LINQ to SQL DataContext?

I have written some code as below, but doesn't work as problem with incorrect syntax: Please suggest

```
using (EntityCommand command = new EntityCommand("DELETE VALUE e FROM objEntity.tblTable AS e WHERE e.Id="+int.Parse(TextBox1.Text)+"", objConn))
        { 
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
```

Comment: sad story but your query is prone of sql injection, try this [tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/AddparameterstotheSqlCommand.htm)

Comment: This tutorial only describes SQL command objects, but I m looking out for delete with entity command objects

Comment: i see.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738684.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, that link is describing about data select from DB, but I have tried the same but not select I want to perform delete operation instead. But Query I am passing in Entity command is not correct. Have you got any ideas regards to delete query syntax as shown above in code. Please suggest

Comment: you have create parameters to delete.. just follow the example, i will try to answer but im busy for now `:D`

Comment: Is there any reason to not use EF method?

Comment: @NunoCarmo: Want to Give a Better Try With EntityClient Objects rather SQL DBCommand Objects